# PHP SQL Order by date and id

Tags: php, sql

This is my PHP SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Buchungen 
WHERE Buchungen.konto = '".$value_entry."'
ORDER BY datum DESC
```

Is it possible to order this by the `newest id` for each date? When i have 3 entries, from 18.11.2013, i want the newest entry on top. The latest entry has the largest id from this date. I don't want to add an time column in my sql table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace:

```
ORDER BY datum DESC
```

With:

```
ORDER BY datum DESC, id DESC
```

Basically, this means: Order by `datum desc` but whenever there are duplicated values for `datum` then order those values by `id desc`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a timestamp field to your table, and sort by that.
Or you could have an auto_increment index (can't see your schema, so I can't judge if you have it)

> SELECT * FROM Buchungen WHERE Buchungen.konto = '".$value_entry."'ORDER BY datum DESC, id DESC

Ps, I hope $value_entry is cleaned/escaped user input if it is user input